# .NET Core Dynamic Compilation

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, codedom

I am attempting to port some .NET Framework code to .NET Core. The code uses CodeDOM to perform dynamic compilation.

I've learned that .NET Core removed CodeDOM but I haven't found a drop-in replacement. So, my question is: **how can I replicate the functionality that used to be provided by CodeDOM?**

Comment: Use [Roslyn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852926/microsoft-roslyn-vs-codedom).

Comment: Can you provide some code as an example of what you were doing previously?

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core uses Roslyn as a replacement for CodeDOM, but Roslyn seems to be a much improved version.

This link is for the Roslyn wiki, which contains tutorials. [Roslyn Git Wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki)